# OpenOffice 4.1.1 not installing in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

I REALLY need to install OpenOffice because of a specific program that doesn't work with LibreOffice.

I've tried EVERY suggestion of how to install it I found in this and other sites, and no joy.

When I try the tar it always says the files unrecoverable.

Please help me? I need simple and clear instructions, but I don't need to be told to just stick to LibreOffice because that is not an option.

Comment: What tar you have tried here? The tar file for OpenOffice?

Comment: Please provide the error messages you got. Be more specific as to what you have already tried. E.g. have you done all steps described here: https://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-deb? Have you verified the download? (e.g.  with md5sum)

Comment: I followed all the steps in the page you mention and in others,  including this same forum. I always get the message that it is not possible to recover the file. or directory not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove LibreOffice by typing in terminal`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`

  - Check your Java version: `java -version`(To install java [Click here](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/))
- For you(32 bit) type in terminal :
  `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.0/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz`
- Then type: `tar xzf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz`
- Go to right directory: `cd en-US/DEBS/`
- Install OpenOffice: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
- Integrate with desktop: `cd desktop-integration/`
- Install integration: `sudo dpkg -i openoffice4.0-debian-menus*.deb`
- Start OpenOffice

Comment: Thank you SO much! This worked like a charm.... I was beginning to despair! You are a star!

Answer (score 0):

First try reinstalling Ubuntu14.04, then use the 'purge' command to eliminate all LibreOffice-files.

Then by the downloaded '....install-deb_sv.tar.gz' file , perform an extraction and you will getting SV-map and sub-map DEBS.

Then unpack the files in DEBS with the Terminal-prog. with cmd 'sudo dpkg -i *.deb' and then the same cmd on the file in the maå 'desktop-integration'.

And then, voila, all AOO-files were created.

It is still curious that the 'normal' way to make the installation may not work for few 32-bit processors...

Hope this helps you..